# Session variable and determine the price value

Tags: php, mysql

do you know how to write the PHP coding for MySQL if I select `$_SESSION['room1']`, the room price is $100, `$_SESSION['room2]`, the room price is $200.

the session are stored from drop down list.

After determine the price of the room, I will use the value to multiple 10% for the deposit of reservation.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. If you have tried nothing - please try first. If you have absolutely no idea where to start - please research first. Option 4 - hire some one

Comment: That's great, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not exactly clear but i have understood that you are want to use a session variable to store the data retrieved from your mysql database.

so let me write a demo code:

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION['nameofvar'] = "value to assign";

?>
```

There is no different method assign to session variable for mysql result, all the session variable values are assigned in a same manner.